# MYSQL PHP query to get data from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter data based on one table, but i dont know the correct usage for the select from function in php mysql. The below code shows what i am trying to do, but I think you can use multiple SELECT.

```
$query_Student = "SELECT Project_Title, Project_Lecturer FROM projects WHERE Project_id = 
 (SELECT Proj_id FROM project_course WHERE Cour_id = (SELECT Course_id from courses WHERE     
Code = (SELECT Course FROM users WHERE Username = ".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."))"
```

Can anyone offer any assistance to what I need to write instead?

Comment: What does this query give you?

Comment: try the "union" syntax to perform several queries once ...

Comment: The output is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Proj_id FROM project_course WHERE Cour_id = (SELECT Course_id from course' at line 1"

Comment: @NathanLinkAbiola Ignore what Hamza said about "union", that's not what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not exactly clear to me, but to make your query work you need to put single quotes around `$_SESSION['MM_Username']`, like gogowitsch already said.

Also another closing paranthese is missing. So your query should look like this:

```
$query_Student = "SELECT Project_Title, Project_Lecturer FROM projects WHERE Project_id = 
 (SELECT Proj_id FROM project_course WHERE Cour_id = (SELECT Course_id from courses WHERE     
Code = (SELECT Course FROM users WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."')))"
```

**But...**

That is not a very well written query.

I'm just guessing now, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
p.Project_Title, 
p.Project_Lecturer 
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN project_course pc ON p.Project_id = pc.Proj_id
INNER JOIN courses c ON pc.Cour_id = c.Course_id
INNER JOIN users u ON c.Code = u.Course
WHERE u.Username = 'yourUserName';
```

If not, show us the tables you are using (do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE projects;` and so on for every table you are using and post it here) and maybe what output you expect, then we can really help.

Comment: That seems to work, however i realise that i require the forename and surname of the user linked to that project in the users table aswell. Would i create a new join query or can i add it onto the existing one.

Comment: @NathanLinkAbiola Is the fore- and surname in the table users? If yes, just add it in the `SELECT` clause. Like this: `SELECT 
p.Project_Title, 
p.Project_Lecturer, u.forename, u.surname FROM projects p ...`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add quotes around the username. Can `$_SESSION['MM_Username']` be a string?